Cumulative SUM formula
I want a cumulative formula that will return the running total for each value in column B.
For example, in the rows in column A:

=SUM(B$1:B1)
=SUM(B$1:B2)
=SUM(B$1:B3)
=SUM(B$1:B4)
etc.

I would like to get get this as an array formula so that I don’t have to drag the formula every time I add more data.
I haven't been able to solve this myself.


SCAN Function
Scans an array and produces intermediate values by application of a LAMBDA function to each value.
TOCOL was used to remove blank rows from column B.
=SCAN(0, TOCOL(B2:B,1), LAMBDA(a,v, a+v)) 

MAP w/ SEQUENCE

MAP a SEQUENCE of numbers matching the number of populated rows in your column, one by one, into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row number in x
The LAMBDA's formula takes x and creates another SEQUENCE of numbers up to and including x that CHOOSEROWS uses as the row numbers from column B to return.
The CHOOSEROWS function is wrapped in SUM which returns the total up to that row x, then the process repeats for the next x until they are all done.

=MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B1:B)), LAMBDA(x, 
   SUM(CHOOSEROWS(B1:B, SEQUENCE(x))))) 

